# How to load video uri to cast video on android tv instead of url

Tags: android

I have to cast local video uri on android tv using google cast sdk. All solutions available are using url. I tried to do that using uri and path but it didn't worked. How can I convert uri to url. Below is what I tried

```
private fun getMediaInfo(name: String, path: String, photoMode: Boolean): MediaInfo {
        val context = requireActivity().applicationContext
        val wifiManager = context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
        val wifiInfo = wifiManager.connectionInfo
        val ipAddress = Inet4Address.getByAddress(
            BigInteger.valueOf(wifiInfo.ipAddress.toLong()).toByteArray()
        ).hostAddress
        errorLog("ipAddress :: $ipAddress")
        val url = "http://" + ipAddress + ":" + PORT + "/" + path
        errorLog("url :: $url")
        val mediaMetadata =
            if (photoMode) MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO) else MediaMetadata(
                MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE
            )
        mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, name)
        mediaMetadata.addImage(WebImage(Uri.parse(url)))
        mediaMetadata.addImage(WebImage(Uri.parse(url)))

        return if (photoMode) MediaInfo.Builder(url)
            .setContentType("image/jpeg")
            .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_NONE)
            .setMetadata(mediaMetadata)
            .build()
        else MediaInfo.Builder(url)
            .setContentType("video/mp4")
            .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
            .setMetadata(mediaMetadata)
            .build()

    }
```

in this code i am trying to convert uri to url

```
val context = requireActivity().applicationContext
        val wifiManager = context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
        val wifiInfo = wifiManager.connectionInfo
        val ipAddress = Inet4Address.getByAddress(
            BigInteger.valueOf(wifiInfo.ipAddress.toLong()).toByteArray()
        ).hostAddress
        errorLog("ipAddress :: $ipAddress")
        val url = "http://" + ipAddress + ":" + PORT + "/" + path
```

but it's not working. If I pass any url of public video it works

If I pass any url of public video available on google it works fine

Comment: A Chromecast or other Google Cast target does not have access to media on the Android device. If you are good at security, you could embed an HTTP server in your app, have it serve media, and use a URL to your HTTP server with your cast request.

Comment: @CommonsWare we can convert path to url in same way as doing above in code snippet. Issue was in starting cast service.